# Finding xml node and child attribute

Tags: xml, vba

I need to find node name of Dataset and all attributes of its child node. So I used for next loop to find the values of FCDA and its attributes. But the codes is not working. Can you help me, where I am wrong.

### XML Data

```
<DataSet name="StatUrgA" desc="Primary Switch and General Status">
   <FCDA lnClass="LLN0" prefix="" doName="Loc" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="GGIO" prefix="ENMC" doName="Ind2" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="GGIO" prefix="ENMC" doName="Ind3" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="GGIO" prefix="ENMC" doName="Ind1" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="XCBR" prefix="CB" doName="BlkCls" lnInst="10" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="XCBR" prefix="CB" doName="BlkOpn" lnInst="10" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="CSWI" prefix="CB" doName="Pos" lnInst="10" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="XSWI" prefix="DCO" doName="BlkCls" lnInst="15" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="XSWI" prefix="DCO" doName="BlkOpn" lnInst="15" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="CSWI" prefix="DCO" doName="Pos" lnInst="15" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="XSWI" prefix="ESW" doName="BlkCls" lnInst="16" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="XSWI" prefix="ESW" doName="BlkOpn" lnInst="16" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="CSWI" prefix="ESW" doName="Pos" lnInst="16" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="GGIO" prefix="PS" doName="DPCSO" lnInst="2" ldInst="LD0" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="GGIO" prefix="PS" doName="DPCSO" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD0" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="LPHD" prefix="" doName="InOv" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="LPHD" prefix="" doName="InOv" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD0" fc="ST" />
</DataSet>
<DataSet name="StatIed" desc="Status">
   <FCDA lnClass="LLN0" prefix="" doName="Beh" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="XCBR" prefix="CB" doName="Beh" lnInst="10" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="CSWI" prefix="CB" doName="Beh" lnInst="10" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="XSWI" prefix="DCO" doName="Beh" lnInst="15" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="CSWI" prefix="DCO" doName="Beh" lnInst="15" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="XSWI" prefix="ESW" doName="Beh" lnInst="16" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="CSWI" prefix="ESW" doName="Beh" lnInst="16" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
   <FCDA lnClass="LPHD" prefix="" doName="PhyHealth" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="ST" />
</DataSet>
<DataSet name="MeasFlt" desc="Measurands">
   <FCDA lnClass="MMXU" prefix="UI" doName="TotW" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="MX" />
   <FCDA lnClass="MMXU" prefix="UI" doName="PhV" lnInst="2" ldInst="LD1" fc="MX" />
   <FCDA lnClass="MMXU" prefix="UI" doName="A" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="MX" />
   <FCDA lnClass="MMXU" prefix="UI" doName="PhV" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="MX" />
   <FCDA lnClass="MMXU" prefix="UI" doName="PPV" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="MX" />
   <FCDA lnClass="MMXU" prefix="UI" doName="Hz" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="MX" />
   <FCDA lnClass="MMXU" prefix="UI" doName="TotPF" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="MX" />
   <FCDA lnClass="MMXU" prefix="UI" doName="TotVA" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="MX" />
   <FCDA lnClass="MMXU" prefix="UI" doName="TotVAr" lnInst="1" ldInst="LD1" fc="MX" />
</DataSet>
```

### Code

```
Dim strXml As String
Dim XDoc As Object, root As Object
Filename = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CID").Cells(1, 1).Value
Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
XDoc.async = False: XDoc.validateOnParse = False
strXml = XDoc.Load(Filename)
Set root = XDoc.DocumentElement
For Each datasetnodes In XDoc.ChildNodes
    For Each fcdanodes In XDoc.ChildNodes
        Set List1 = XDoc.SelectNodes("//FCDA")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Datasets").Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = List1(i).getAttribute("ldInst")
        MsgBox List1(i).getAttribute("ldInst")
        i = i + 1
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I have included only one portion of the xml text.  Not included all the xml.

Comment: Your code run without error after I corrected a completely formed XML document.  Please elaborate on what you are is not working.

Comment: sorry for that, i have included only some portions of the xml. I need to traverse on some particular nodes. How i actually go through that. for that purpose i write some codes. It is not working. can u help on that.

Answer (score 1):

AnalystCave has a good tutorial: [Working with XML files in VBA (VBA XML)](http://analystcave.com/vba-xml-working-xml-files/).

### Method 1

Drill down from the Root node to the last leaf.  Every nested `For Each` loop should iterate over the ChildNodes of the `For Each` loop above it.

- XDoc.DocumentElement:Root Node
- XDoc.DocumentElement:Root Node ChildNodes:Dataset
- XDoc.DocumentElement:Root Node ChildNodes:Dataset ChildNodes:FCDA Nodes

---

```
Set root = XDoc.DocumentElement
For Each datasetnodes In root.ChildNodes
    For Each fcdanodes In datasetnodes.ChildNodes
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Datasets").Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = fcdanodes.getAttribute("ldInst")
         i = i + 1
    Next
Next
```

### Method 2

Iterate over a collection of `FCDA` nodes returned by `XDoc.SelectNodes("//FCDA")`

---

```
Set root = XDoc.DocumentElement
For Each fcdanodes In XDoc.SelectNodes("//FCDA")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Datasets").Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = fcdanodes.getAttribute("ldInst")
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: sorry for that, i have included only some portions of the xml. I need to traverse on some particular nodes. How i actually go through that. for that purpose i write some codes. It is not working. can u help on that.

Comment: @Parfait If I had examined the OP's code closer, the problem was blatantly obvious.

Comment: @ThomasInzina , thanks for the update.. First code not working for me. Second one is working. Is it possible to get Dataset name along with second code?